# HTTP POST and GET request for WinXP

Tags: http, logging, post, windows-xp, get

I remember that there is a folder in the c:\Windows\system32 where all the HTTP POST and GET request are logged. I cannot find the folder in the net. Does anybody know where that folder is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles` is one place, I think you can configure this in the IIS control panel.